# Spring batch embedded in Spring MVC application

Tags: spring, web, quartz-scheduler, scheduler

I'm trying to launch my jobs from a web application using using a scheduler (quartz) for programmed executions and http requests for manual execution.

I'm a beginner when it comes to spring so it becomes a bit confusing at times. I'm using Spring Batch in action as reference (http://my.safaribooksonline.com/book/programming/java/9781935182955/running-batch-jobs/ch04lev1sec4)

I have several complications, i need my jobs schedule configuration can be updated from a web app loading data from database. Since most configuration is in xml, I dont know how to manage dynamic configuration.

is this something that can be done?

Comment: Try to write your own batch scheduler.

Comment: I am aiming to do similar thing with same infrastructure but having problem running the scheduler with spring batch in an mvc application. Let me know, what u did for the solution